# Calculating key from seed for UDS service 27(Security access)

Tags: diagnostics, iot-for-automotive

Is there any different method for calculating key for security access service except taking 2's complement.If it is so please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm for the key calculation of SecurityAccess service depends on the particular ECU specification. To make it hard to gain access without permission usually a algorithm which requires a shared-secret-key is used (only known by the ECU and by the applications who need access).

Commonly used algorithms are i.e.

- Bitwise XOR operation on the seed
- Bitwise Shift and/or Rotation on the seed
- AES Encryption/Decryption of the seed (symmetric)
- RSA Encryption/Decryption of the seed (asymmetric)
- Combinations of these

If you asked this question to find out how the SecurityAccess on a particular ECU works, there is no way to know without the ECU specification or lots of reverse-engineering.

If you asked this question to decide on a good algorithm to be used for a new ECU, it is highly advisable to use a widely adopted cryptographic algorithm instead of reinventing it because the established algorithms are designed and reviewed by field-experts (i.e. AES-256).

Comment: how what's the purpose of key computation, is it to verify the tester identity ? if so what's the concept, is it just that the ECU and tester compute a key using the same seed and the purpose is to verify that they use the same secret algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat "standard" seems the usage of XTEA algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA
I have seen several ECUs using it.

The (UDS) service is implemented to give secure access to internal parameters of the ECU only to approved personnel.
The procedure is simple:

- Request the seed from the ECU
- So if you have the master key you can generate with the XTEA and the seed the individual KEY.
- Send seed and KEY within allowed time frame (2 secs ? implementation dependent?) back
- ==> unlocked

Now the supported UDS commands (some are standardized, some are implementation dependent) are free to use.